# Building a voice bot with Amazon Lex in India

Tags: amazon-web-services, chatbot, amazon-lex, amazon-polly

On their website, AWS has mentioned about their high-quality speech recognition and NLP and the ability to create a voice bot.

If need to create voice bot using AWS Lex but I do not need to create it for a call center but rather make calls from my end i.e. I need to initiate the call.

My question is what service should I use to make the calls as Amazon connect is not available in India. Is their a service/product with which I could integrate the Lex.

Answer (score 1):

Since Amazon Connect is not available in India yet, you can use services like Exotel or Knowlarity. Both have APIs, so you can trigger calls using AWS Lambda and Lex. If your use case is simple enough with just IVR changing with user inputs, you don't even need Lex. You can just use Exotel or Knowlarity's built-in IVR features.

Answer (score 0):

Amazon Connect still not available in India.
But you can try If you change your address to us location.

You will get US number and use textmenow android/IOS to make free call to US so you can test how Amazon AI Voice bot talk with you.